# Move an answer to different post?

Tags: discussion, support

[What is the punishment for homosexuals?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5435/9123) is the target question.

I've found an [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12843/9123) but I reckon is present at the wrong place. Can the mods move it, because I feel it's a good answer for the target question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Not because I disagree with your argument, but because that just isn't a tool that moderators *have*. Or, at least, we can't really do anything that you can't already do here: Write a new answer which attributes the original.

If you think there's valuable information worth saving (because, yeah, it clearly has no place on the original question at all and really should've been caught/flagged/deleted well before now (and seriously: who keeps upvoting these things?!)) you can quote it as you would any other reference in a new answer. But, honestly, is it worth it?

The post is itself sorely lacking in references; it makes a number of assertions (which may or may not be true) but doesn't really back any of them up beyond a vague allusion to "According to my book…". Surely if anyone wanted to write a new answer that actually *answers* the target question, they could find a better source than that (especially given the OP of the target question is explicitly *asking* for hadith references).